# Two Controller Loading on ng-click function in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am navigating to profile page which has `profileCtrl` and ng-click function is in `hmplController`, When I click on ng-click both controller will load I mean `hmplController` and `profileCtrl`, This will happen only first time. After clearing cache again on ng-click both controller.

Here is my code.

```
homepal.controller('hmplController', function ($scope, $cookies,$mdSidenav) {

        $scope.profile=function(){
             $location.path("/profile/index");

            }

        $scope.myShortlists=function(){
           $location.path("/profile/myShortlists");

        }

         $scope.recentlyViewed=function(){
         $location.path("/profile/recentlyViewed");

        }

        $scope.enquiredProperties=function(){
         $location.path("/profile/enquiredProperties");

        }

       $scope.accountSettings=function(){
          $location.path("/profile/accountSettings");  
        }



});
```

My `routeProvider` as below

```
sidemenu.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider


         .when('/profile/index', {        
            templateUrl: '../view/profile.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        })

          .when('/propCountry/:cityName',{
            templateUrl: '../view/propertyInCity.html',
            controller: 'cityController'
        })

          .when('/profile/myShortlists',{  
            templateUrl: '../template/myshortlist.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        })

        .when('/profile/recentlyViewed',{  
            templateUrl: '../template/recentlyViewed.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        })


        .when('/profile/enquiredProperties',{  
            templateUrl: '../template/EnqProperties.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        })

        .when('/profile/accountSettings',{  
            templateUrl: '../template/AccSettings.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        })


        .when('/builders/:id', {
            templateUrl: '../template/listpagefilter.html',
            controller: 'buildersCtrl'
            })


        .when('/builders/:id/property/:property_id', {
            templateUrl: '../view/property-details.html',
            controller: 'unitTypeCtrl'
        })

        .when('/property/:property_id', {
            templateUrl: '../view/property-details.html',
            controller: 'unitTypeCtrl'
        })

        .when('/location/:city_name/:location_id', {
            templateUrl: '../template/listpagefilter.html',
            controller: 'buildersCtrl'
        })
        .when('/:city_id', {
            templateUrl: '../template/listpagefilter.html',
            controller: 'buildersCtrl'
        })

        .when('/sublocation/:sub_location_id', {
            templateUrl: '../template/listpagefilter.html',
            controller: 'buildersCtrl'
        })

        .when('/nearby/:neighbourhood_id',{
            templateUrl: '../template/listpagefilter.html',
            controller: 'buildersCtrl'
        })

        .when('/filterate/:query',{
            templateUrl: '../template/listpagefilter.html',
            controller: 'buildersCtrl'
        })

         .when('/quicklinks/homeloan', {        
            templateUrl: '../view/homeloan.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        })


        .when('/quicklinks/docHome', {        
            templateUrl: '../view/quickdoc.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        })
        .when('/quicklinks/emiCal', {        
            templateUrl: '../view/emiCalculator.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        })
        .when('/quicklinks/buyingSteps', {        
            templateUrl: '../view/property_buying.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        })
        .when('/quicklinks/vaastuTips', {        
            templateUrl: '../view/vaastu.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        })
        .when('/quicklinks/nriService', {        
            templateUrl: '../view/nri.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        })


        .when('/quicklinks/homepalmedia', {        
            templateUrl: '../view/homepal_media.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        })

        .when('/quicklinks/aboutus', {        
            templateUrl: '../view/homepal_aboutus.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        })

        .when('/quicklinks/homebuilders', {        
            templateUrl: '../view/homepal_builders.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        })

         .when('/quicklinks/services', {        
            templateUrl: '../view/homepal_ourservices.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        })

          .when('/quicklinks/contact', {        
            templateUrl: '../view/homepal_contactus.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        }) 

}])
```

Profile Controller

```
sidemenu.controller('profileCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$http', 
    'allServices', '$document', 'PropertyDetails', '$routeParams', '$window', '$location', 
    '$anchorScroll', 'customVariables','$mdDialog','raisedEnquiryDetails','$anchorScroll', function(a, b, c, d, e, f, h, r, w, l, s, cust,v,rse,scrl) {

 e.getProjectwishlist().then(function(result) {
           alert(JSON.stringify(result));
        }, function(error) {
            alert("error");
        });




var srchCls_Element = angular.element(document.querySelector('.navbar-affixed-top'));

        if (srchCls_Element) {
            srchCls_Element.addClass('listing-navbar');
        }

a.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(scope, next, current) {
            b.homepage = true;
            b.filter = false;
            b.innerHeader = "";
            b.searchFilter = false;
          srchCls_Element.removeClass('listing-navbar');

        });



    a.homeloan=function(){
        c.path('/quicklinks/homeloan');

        }

    a.docHome=function(){
         c.path('/quicklinks/docHome');

        }

}]);
```

Comment: Verify your partial for any possible ng-controller.

Comment: create a plunk for the same, for better understanding.